# Host the top level domain in shopify and the subdomain on cpanel

Tags: shopify, cpanel

Is that possible? Can you share your answer guys, thanks! Would love to implement this

Answer (score 0):

If you understand how DNS works, you own your own domain name, you can make DNS entries for your domain that would support Shopify and a subdomain. There is no magic to it. Straight up, DNS.